# differences between two timespan returns negative

Tags: c#

I am in a HR project and I need to define Shift for Employees 
Shift had two feilds for punchcards reading , Swipein and swipeOut . I use two datetimepicker with format as time and showupdown as true to set the swipe in and out time 
and read like this

```
public void calculateduration()
    {
        TimeSpan swipein = dtp_toTime.Value.TimeOfDay;
        TimeSpan swipeout = dtp_FromTime.Value.TimeOfDay;
        TimeSpan duration = dtp_toTime.Value.TimeOfDay - dtp_FromTime.Value.TimeOfDay;
        MessageBox.Show(duration.ToString());

    }
```

in my SQL server database I had all these three feilds swipein ,swipeout,duration as Time datatype ,and I want to insert these values there

For testing I give four values

Swipein     Swipeout        Duration(output displayed)
8 am        4 pm           8 hrs >>>>its same day sday shift

3 pm       10 pm           8 hrs >> same day daynight shifty

10 pm   6 am(next day)    -16 hrs >>> the prblm..8 must come here

Any Idea pls
or can any one tell me an idea to check whether the duration recieved is negative like

```
if(duration <0)
{
duration= 24-duration;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the values before subtracting them:

```
TimeSpan duration;
if (swipeout >= swipein) {
  duration = swipeout - swipein;
} else {
  duration = swipeout + new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0, 0) - swipein;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the TimeSpan structure is intended to represent a time interval, rather than a specific time. So in this case, using TimeSpan for duration makes sense, but swipein and swipeout would be better represented by DateTime.

```
public void calculateduration()
{
    DateTime swipein = dtp_toTime.Value;
    DateTime swipeout = dtp_FromTime.Value;
    TimeSpan duration = swipeout - swipein;
    MessageBox.Show(duration.ToString());
}
```

(Of course, this assumes that dtp_ToTime.Value and dtp_FromTime.Value are DateTimes, but I'm guessing they are...)

Comment: but I didnt want the date part t also to go to database ,this is the flace where i define the Shift time  it doesnot need a date it just says shift A is from  this time to this thime evaery day ..I will be using this time for every swipe in machine  ...anyway was a good idea forwarded by you